# Xib file on static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, xib

I'm taking over a project I did not start and I'm still a junior, so I need some help to clarify my mind.
I'm developing a library for iOS 7.0 and up.
This library is then distributed trough cocoapods.

I've build a custom view and how I have a .xib file containing it.
It works perfectly in my dev app (because I'm using directly the code), but when I test it in my staging app (which loads the library trough a local pod) I get

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Jack/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/899B54FC-8A37-4182-9D89-109251B58555/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/36A3B225-AEF2-42B7-8AEC-5D930F4C4BCA/StagingApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'CheckBoxWithText''
```

The .xib file is in the copy file build phase and is part of the target I'm using to build the library.

I'm loading the xib like this

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBoxWithText" owner:self options:nil];
```

But it crashes as soon as the components gets loaded on screen.
Some people were saying to use the bundle of your library, but I don't think my library has an identifier ( can't see it on info).
I tried using

```
[[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.company.project"] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBoxWithText" owner:self options:nil];
```

but it does not load anything.

I've spent the afternoon reading possible solution but now I've a lot of confusion in my head.

A static library (like mine) is not supposed to contain resources like xib, yet I'm packing some images with it. Am I missing something here?
I've read a [tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/) about a guy who achieved this using a budle target, but I haven't really understood how he did it and how would I use that target given that I'm supposed to use my aggregate target to build the library.

A dynamic framework would solve the problem if not for the fact that I can't use it on iOS7.0.

Is my only option to build the layout programmatically?
Or am I just missing something and it's possible to pack the .xib file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods doesn't seem to pick up `.xib` files when you specify them using `resources` in your `.podspec`. Using `resource_bundles` instead works fine.

So the `.podspec` would read:

```
s.resource_bundles = { 'CheckBoxWithText' => ['CheckBoxWithText.xib'] }
```

The Nib would be loaded like this:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForURL:[NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"CheckBoxWithText"
        withExtension:@"bundle"]];
NSArray* nib = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"USACheckBoxWithText" owner:self options:nil];
```

Now there is another [bug in CocoaPods which prevents asset catalogs to be loaded from `resource_bundles`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4501). You should avoid asset catalogs for now.

Note that both bugs would be solved if you use iOS 8 as minimum and develop your Pod in Swift.

Comment: I've tried `[[NSBundle bundleForClass: FeedbackController.class] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBoxWithText" owner:self options:nil];` as well as `[[NSBundle bundleForClass: [FeedbackController class]] loadNibNamed:@"CheckBoxWithText" owner:self options:nil];` but the error is still there

Comment: How did you add the `.xib` file to your CocoaPod? Using [resources](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resources) or [resource_bundles](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles)?

Comment: I wasn't really sure, so I went for both:
 `s.resource  = "ubForm/Images.xcassets/**/*.*"
 s.resource  = "ubForm/**/*.xib"
 s.resource_bundles = "ubForm/**/*.xib"`

Comment: There are multiple issues. First you should only use one of the approaches not both. Let's opt for `resources`. Second you should specify the asset catalog itself, not it's children. `s.resources = ['ubForm/Images.xcassets', 'ubForm/**/*.xib']` - Next thing would be that you check the folder `Pods/CheckBoxWithText` in the project which uses your Pod. Find the Nib file in there and check how it's called and where it is located. Don't forget to perform a `pod update` first after changing your podspec.

Comment: I've done what you said and updated my podspec. Looking in the pod folder of my staging app I can see the resource folder with all the images, but I can not see any .xib file. I've tried various way of specifying the resource folder, just to be sure.
If my podspec was being ignored I should not have the images catalog as well, so it's not that I think.

Comment: I just set up a test project and there seems to be a limitation that you cannot use `.xib`s with `resources`. It only works with `resource_bundles`. Will update my answer.